# How make segue called after another method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a TableViewCell with CutomCells,that includes images view, when user selects some row, the image that is in this row should be shown in another viewController.
Connection among these Controllers is done through segue, where I tries to set the image.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ImageVC"])
    {
        ImageViewController * ivc = segue.destinationViewController;
        ivc.myTemporaryImage = [self.dataDictionary objectForKey:self.names[self.selectedCell]];
    }
}
```

to define which one row was selected I use TableViewDelegates method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   self.selectedCell = indexPath.row;
    [self.dataDictionary objectForKey:self.names[indexPath.row]];
}
```

The issue here that image is not reflected, cause firstly fires method: prepareForSegue, and only after that - didSelectRowAtIndexPath. But I need to change this order. Could you advice how to do this?

Also I tried to create ImageViewController programmatically, without using segue, directly in method didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but in this image is not shown in this case.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [self.dataDictionary objectForKey:self.names[indexPath.row]];

    ImageViewController * ivc = [[ImageViewController alloc]init];
    ivc.myTemporaryImage = [self.savedImages objectForKey:self.names[indexPath.row]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
}
```

Could you please how to manage this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the direct reference to your segue in your cell, then, in your tableView delegate call it programmatically:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   self.selectedCell = indexPath.row;
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ImageVC", sender: [self.savedImages objectForKey:self.names[indexPath.row]]]
}
```

Then in prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ImageVC"])
    {
        ImageViewController * ivc = segue.destinationViewController;
        ivc.myTemporaryImage = sender;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly!!! Thanks a lot)))

Answer (score 1):

I think you can save the indexPath at the willSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it now))

Comment: Jason, unfortunately, when this method is implemented, segue is ignored - it is not fired at all.